# Is it possible to read standard error after writing to it in the same process?

Tags: c#

This is what I tried, but error == ""

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardError());
Console.Error.WriteLine("An error has occurred");
Console.Error.Flush();
string error = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

The purpose being that I need to write a test for a class which is writing to standard error. I want to check the errors being written are correct, but ideally I don't want to modify the class itself.

Comment: Well, you already wrote the test.  Does it work?  You tell us.  If it doesn't work, what happens?

Comment: no, error string is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I have found. Set the Console.Error to be an extended TextWriter that intercepts the text being written. I only overrode WriteLine(string) as that is all I need.

```
TextWriter oldWriter = Console.Error;
ErrorCapturer errorCapturer = new ErrorCapturer();
Console.SetError(errorCapturer);
Console.Error.WriteLine("An error has occured");
string error = errorCapturer.ReadToEnd();
Console.SetError(oldWriter);

class ErrorCapturer : TextWriter
{
    string _buffer="";
    public override void WriteLine(string line)
    {
        _buffer += line + Environment.NewLine;
        base.WriteLine(line);
    }

    public string ReadToEnd()
    {
        string ret = _buffer;
        _buffer = "";
        return ret;
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.ASCII; }
    }
}
```